# Effecient way to update a large set of objects with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

What are the principles of efficient select'n'update of large sets of objects via Hibernate?

- Each object could be updated independently
- Required: efficient memory usage (no out of memory error)
- Required: efficient select
- Required: efficient flushing into DB

*I believe stored procedures or the single `update` query could be much more effective than dealing with each object separately but I want no use them now. I'm using Grails 2.2 actually.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [batch updates](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html), they were designed for exactly this purpose.